# Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined. Parse.com migration

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

Great nightmare with `parse.com` announcing they will be closing down next year. Now I'm trying to test their suggested solution using `MongoDB`. The problem is, I'm stuck with `javascript` errors. I got the git in [parse-servir-github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server)
, added my app settings and ran the `node index.js`. Now, I'm getting the error when trying to access the local server:

> parse-server-example running on port 1337.
>   /Users/ferrojr/DeveloperTools/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:120
>   this._router.handle(req, res, function(err) {
>                 ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'handle' of undefined
>       at Function.app.handle (/Users/ferrojr/DeveloperTools/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:120:15)
>       at Server.app (/Users/ferrojr/DeveloperTools/parse-server/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:28:9)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>       at Server.emit (events.js:172:7)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:528:12)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:88:23)

Here's is the code in `application.js`.

```
app.handle = function(req, res, done) {
  var env = this.get('env');

  this._router.handle(req, res, function(err) {
    if (done) {
      return done(err);
    }

    // unhandled error
    if (err) {
      // default to 500
      if (res.statusCode < 400) res.statusCode = 500;
      debug('default %s', res.statusCode);

      // respect err.status
      if (err.status) res.statusCode = err.status;

      // production gets a basic error message
      var msg = 'production' == env
        ? http.STATUS_CODES[res.statusCode]
        : err.stack || err.toString();
      msg = escapeHtml(msg);

      // log to stderr in a non-test env
      if ('test' != env) console.error(err.stack || err.toString());
      if (res.headersSent) return req.socket.destroy();
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
      res.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(msg));
      if ('HEAD' == req.method) return res.end();
      res.end(msg);
      return;
    }

    // 404
    debug('default 404');
    res.statusCode = 404;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    if ('HEAD' == req.method) return res.end();
    res.end('Cannot ' + escapeHtml(req.method) + ' ' + escapeHtml(req.originalUrl) + '\n');
  });
};
```

Anyway, I'm a `iOS developer` with no experience on `node.js`, I'm just trying to follow `parse.com` tutorial and setup my database to use `mongoDB` and `parse server` locally.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After "var env = this.get('env');", please add "console.dir(this._router);" to log the content of the this._router variable. I guess it is undefined, and that causes the error.

The result should appear in your node.js command prompt.

Comment: Take a look at the following link and see if it helps you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457056/simple-express-js-application-running-with-error